# excution in a folder that dosen't have the dlls used

Tags: c++-cli

there is any way to have an execution file (*.exe) that run in a folder that doesn't have the dlls referenced by the project??

for example:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace dllNet;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    dllNet::Class1::SayHi();
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

i want to execute my project without dllNet.dll

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, the program cannot run without the libraries needed.